# i couldn't insert data to database in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i couldn't insert data to database and no error display. i try var_dump($this->mberita->get_berita()); but array(0){}. I am a newbie in Codeigniter and couldn't really figure out how to solve this.

modal

```
function get_berita()
    {
        $this->db->order_by('id_berita','asc');
        $data = $this->db->get('berita_ukm');
        return $data->result();
    }

    //untuk menambah berita
    function insert_berita($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert('berita_ukm', $data);
    }
```

controller

```
function index()
    {
        $this->data['berita'] = $this->mberita->get_berita();
        $this->data['title'] ='UKM Taekwondo | berita';
        $this->data['orang'] = $this->mlogin->dataPengguna($this->session->userdata('username'));
        $this->data['contents'] = $this->load->view('admin/berita/view_berita', $this->data, true);
        $this->load->view('template/wrapper/admin/wrapper_ukm',$this->data);
    }



function tambah_berita()
    {

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('id_berita', 'Id Berita', 'required|numeric');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('tanggal', 'Tanggal', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('judul_berita', 'Judul Berita', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('content', 'Content', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) 
        {
            $this->load->view('admin/berita/tambah_berita');

        }else{

            $this->load->model('mberita');

            $data = array(
                'id_berita' => $this->input->post('id_berita'),
                'tanggal' => $this->input->post('tanggal'),
                'judul_berita' => $this->input->post('judul_berita'),
                'content' => $this->input->post('content')

            );

            $this->mberita->insert_berita($data);
        }

        $this->data['orang'] = $this->mlogin->dataPengguna($this->session->userdata('username'));
        $this->data['contents'] = $this->load->view('admin/berita/tambah_berita', '', true);
        $this->load->view('template/wrapper/admin/wrapper_ukm',$this->data);
    }
```

Please help me what to do. Thank you.

Comment: try `var_dump($this->db->get('berita_ukm'))` in your model function get_berita() and see what you get

Answer (score 2):

Seems you may be missing the data you want to insert:

```
$this->mberita->insert_berita($data);
```

Comment: Is your insert code being executed? Type `print_r($data);` before `$this->db->insert('berita_ukm', $data);` and see if the array is output.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is in the array data.But you don't pass it to the model.

So rewrite the code in controller as

```
$this->mberita->insert_berita($data);
```

Comment: make sure that you are in the if condition or in else part of the form validation

Comment: it's not working. i already edit controller tambah_berita you can see it and can you tell me where is wrong code?

Comment: you check enetred into the if condition of form validation.That is just print any thing in if loop

Comment: i try print_r($data) but the result is NULL.

Comment: you just give it in controller's else part